# form is not submiting with onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to submit form on image click event but I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'submit'` this error after click event fire.

My Code:

```
<form name="searchRef" id="searchRef" method="get" action="#">
  <input type="text" name="s" id="ref" value="" class="ref_search" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="ref_submit" value="GO" class="ref_submit" />
  </span> <span> <img src="http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/image.php?s=2c556ca62e6fd2a2e4d6ca925fb3fda1&u=8331&dateline=1057444055" alt="Go" onClick="document.getElementById('searchRef').submit();"> </span>
</form>
```

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any input field in your form whose Id is `submit`?

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove/change attribute name of submit button, e.g:

```
name="btnSubmit"
```

Otherwise, submit() method of FORM element is overwritten.

Answer (score 2):

Change your submit button name from `submit` to `ref_submit`

as shown below

```
<input type="submit" name="ref_submit" id="ref_submit" value="GO" class="ref_submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

this is just an idea, but try using

```
document.forms["searchRef"].submit();
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById('searchRef').submit();
```

Comment: submit will still refer to input element, no more submit() method

Answer (score 0):

There is probably already an html element with `id=searchRef` in your page, so the `getElementById()` get the wrong one.

A better solution would be to replace your submit button by an input type=image:

```
<input type="image" name="ref_submit" id="ref_submit" value="GO" class="ref_submit" 
  src="path/to/your/image"  />
```

Notice this will result in server side by a POST request with `$_POST['submit_x']` and `$_POST['submit_y']` (which corresponds to the (x,y) mouse coordinates from the top left of the image)

Comment: `name="submit"` should never be used inside a FORM element

Comment: thanks, I didn't notice that. This seems to be a problem only because jquery is used, right ?

Answer (score 0):

please change the form tag action attribute , repalce `#` with the target `page name say  action.php`, and also add `onsubmit="javascript:return false"` in form tag

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because your `name` attribute as `submit`, try to change the name attribute or try below code.

```
  <img src="http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/image.php?s=2c556ca62e6fd2a2e4d6ca925fb3fda1&u=8331&dateline=1057444055" alt="Go" onclick='window.searchRef.submit();' />
```